# How to add Email field in Checkout page and sending E-mail in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce

I did cart using "commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.4-core" module. I would like to add "Email Id" field when doing a checkout. Actually I need that If user provides different email Id's rather than registered mail-id in "BILLING INFORMATION" and "SHIPPING INFORMATION" then after completion of Checkout process, the product payment details should send mail to those E-mail Id's.

Rules export

```
{ "rules_check_order_for_billing_information_mail" : {
    "LABEL" : "Check order for Billing information Mail",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_checkout_complete" ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "commerce_customer_profile",
            "param_type" : "billing",
            "param_user" : [ "site:current-user" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "entity-created:field-billing-email" ],
          "subject" : "Test Subject for Billing mail",
          "message" : "Test Message for Billing mail",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atlast, I found the solution. Just by Adding Actions -> Send mail -> In Field "TO" -> [commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing:field-billing-email]. Simply I got Mail. Thanks for your Contribution.

Comment: Same answer was given by me..

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using Customer Profile for asking customer billing and shipping address.

- So navigate to 
  Store->Customer profiles->Profile types->Billing/Shipping Information->Manage fields.
- Add one more fields in there for email & make that mandatory.
- Add a checkout rules, put condition like "Entity has field" & check your added field.
- Add a action "Send mail" and select your added field in TO field & organize your template using tokens of commerce-order.

I hope this will work, though there are other way working around code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... My issue is still exists. I tried a lot by Adding a checkout rule, put condition like "Entity has field" and so on.. I worked out with Product related Email Id's by following this video link http://vimeo.com/35773294#at=0. It is working fine. but my above issue is still pending. I am trying from 1 day for this issue... Please make it clear step by step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have made it clear. This is the way how it can be done. If you are facing problem at some particular place, modify your question with your followed step...then only I can do anything... If you have made rule then export that & paste here or at some pastebin..

Comment: @JSinha - You should make habit to accept answer too of those persons who has replied your question with good answer...as I can see you haven't done so far...It is not going to encourage anybody to answer your question again..

Comment: I'll explain clearly.. Plz be there for few minutes.

Comment: (1) Checkout settings -> checkout rules -> Added Checkout rule with name "Check order for Billing information Mail".

(2) Actions -> Add Action -> Create a New Entity -> Value = "Commerce Customer Profile" -> Type (Selected from Dropdown) = Billing Information -> Data selector -> site:current-user  -> SAVE

(3) Again Actions -> Add Action -> Send mail -> entity-created:field-billing-email (Choosed from Data Selector) and other things subject, message written as usual for test.

I think this is wrong trail by me and it is not the process. Plz suggest me the proper way.

Comment: Plz check.. I exported the rule.

Comment: I saw your steps. As I have already wrote in answer that you have to add a field in billing/shipping profile. Then you add a condition like "Entity has a field" and in action select that field in TO address to send mail..I don't think creating entity at the time of checkout and using that field to shoot email will work...

Comment: Yeah.. I am looking for your reply. I'll try as you said and I'll reply you.

Comment: Thanks for Reply.. but it is not working. Plz check the procedure I worked out.

1) I Added "Entity has field" condition then in Data Selector -> I selected "commerce-order" and Field value -> billing_email. -> SAVE

2) If I add Action as Send mail, In Data Selector -> commerce-order:billing_email is not showing... 

From 1st point, In Data Selector these three dropdowns are showing "Site:..", "commerce-order:..", "commerce-order".

Comment: Atlast, I found the solution. Just by Adding Actions -> Send mail -> In Field "TO" -> [commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing:field-billing-email]. Simply I got Mail. Thanks for your Contribution.

Comment: @JSinha - You are funny guy. I gave you same answer aboout using field of billing/shipping profile at checkout rules with method of checking/adding. You didn't bother to check billing profile but you answered yourself for using the field of billing profile & accepted...guys like you should never be helped...